# Assigning two items to variable in python

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a GUI in tkinter and am creating a listbox. I have a csv table in the format as follows:

```
camera_name1,crop_factor1,pixel_size1
camera_name2,crop_factor2,pixel_size2
...
#more rows
...
camera_name94,crop_factor94,pixel_size94
```

with `camera_name` being a string, while `crop_factor` and `pixel_size` are floats. I want to create a listbox that displays all camera names. When I select the corresponding name in the listbox, I need it to assign take the crop factor and pixel size values (i.e. clicking on `camera_name1` gives me the corresponding values of `crop_factor1` and `pixel_size1`)

I would use a dictionary, but I need two values per key, while dictionaries only allow one value per key.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: That assumption is wrong: `>>> dict = {"test":[1,2],"another-test":[3,4]}`.

Comment: The relevant point being that "one value" could be a list, or another dict, or a class instance.

Comment: @RadLexus interesting. I've only seen people use dictionaries with one value assigned, so I made that assumption. Thank you for your input. The code works flawlessly now